# T-SQL: CTE row_number over() wrong result for the first line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression

I have the following `Calendar` table starting at `2014-01-01`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_ISO_CALENDAR](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [YEAR]  AS (datepart(year,[DATE])) PERSISTED,
    [SEMESTER]  AS (case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(7) then '1' else '2' end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [TRIMESTER]  AS (case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(4) then '1' else case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(7) then '2' else case when datepart(month,[DATE])<(10) then '3' else '4' end end end) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [MONTH]  AS (case when len(CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(month,[DATE]),(0)))=(1) then '0'+CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(month,[DATE]),(0)) else CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(month,[DATE]),(0)) end) PERSISTED,
    [WEEK]  AS (case when len(CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(iso_week,[DATE]),(0)))=(1) then '0'+CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(iso_week,[DATE]),(0)) else CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(iso_week,[DATE]),(0)) end),
    [DAY]  AS (case when len(CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(day,[DATE]),(0)))=(1) then '0'+CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(day,[DATE]),(0)) else CONVERT([varchar](2),datepart(day,[DATE]),(0)) end) PERSISTED,
    [WEEKNUMBER]  AS (datepart(iso_week,[DATE])),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I created a stored procedure and added `2014-01-01` up to `2020-12-31`.

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_INSERT_CALENDAR_DAYS_INVERVAL]

      @Increment              CHAR(1),
      @StartDate              DATETIME,
      @EndDate                DATETIME

AS 
BEGIN    
WITH cteRange (DateRange) AS (
            SELECT @StartDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, DateRange)
                  END
            FROM cteRange
            WHERE DateRange <= 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, -1, @EndDate)
                  END)

      INSERT INTO [TO_BDB].[dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_ISO_CALENDAR] ([DATE])
      SELECT DateRange
      FROM cteRange
```

Then, I'd like to retrieve the absolute week numbering, following the logic: current week - 1 (last week), is week Zero (0), and I want to look 12 weeks back and 6 weeks forward to the future.

```
with absolute_weeks as (
  select distinct YEAR, WEEK
from [TO_BDB].[dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_ISO_CALENDAR]
where DATEADD(week, 0, DATE) between cast(DATEADD(WEEK, -12, GETDATE())  as date) 
                   and cast(DATEADD(WEEK, +6, GETDATE())  as date) 
)
select *, (row_number() over (order by YEAR, WEEK) - 13) as relative_week
from absolute_weeks 
order by YEAR, WEEK;
```

I get the following result and weeks -11 to +6 are correct but for some reason, the week -12 is incorrect. Can you explain why and how to fix?:

```
YEAR WEEK relative_week
----------------------
2014    01  -12
2014    43  -11
2014    44  -10
2014    45  -9
2014    46  -8
2014    47  -7
2014    48  -6
2014    49  -5
2014    50  -4
2014    51  -3
2014    52  -2
2015    01  -1
2015    02  0
2015    03  1
2015    04  2
2015    05  3
2015    06  4
2015    07  5
2015    08  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KekuSemau pointed out the problem is to do with the ISOWEEK of 2014-12-31 being 1. You could work around this by ordering on DATE instead or YEAR,WEEK, for example;

```
select year,week,(row_number() over (order by min([DATE])) - 13) as relative_week
from [dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_ISO_CALENDAR]
where [DATE] between DATEADD(WEEK, -12, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(WEEK, +6, GETDATE()) 
group by year,week
order by min([DATE])
```

You may need to test this when 'today' is at the start and end of the week to make sure the behaviour suits your purpose.

By the way - kudos for putting a question together properly, working code, clear question etc - there don't seem to be many like this :)

**Edit1**

Here's a completely different approach that does work (I think :)

```
;with cteNumbers as (select top 20 row_number() over (order by object_id) -13 as rn from sys.objects)
select c.year,c.week,n.rn
from cteNumbers n
join [dbo].[TO_BDB_NOSSCE_ISO_CALENDAR] c on c.date = cast(dateadd(d, n.rn*7, getdate()) as date)
```

You will still need to test this to ensure it does what you want when run at the start and end of the week.

Hope this helps,

Rhys

Comment: Perfect, Rhys, you saved the day. Thank you very much, it works perfectly.

Comment: oh, it still returns 2014-01 but as week -2

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that e. g.

```
DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '20141231');
```

actually returns `1` - which is correct but messes up your data.

You could work with a seperate field for the Year of the ISO_Week in the base table, something like this:
`ISOWEEKYEAR = YEAR(d) + CASE WHEN DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, d) = 1 AND MONTH(d) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`